# 内部共有リンクを探し出す

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

ドメイン内部で共有リンクを利用している一覧の抽出をしたいと考えております。

利用環境：Google workspace for Education Fundamentals

Google社サポートには既存GUIでは対応できないと回答を頂いています。

何かしらの対処方法など御座いましたらご教示頂きたいです。